# Enumeration type check

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, optimization, arduino

I have a function that gets an operand of a specific enum type that is predefined. For safety reasons, I want the function to test if the operand belongs to the specific enum type. How can I do that?

Comment: you can make test case against the domain of all enms

Comment: C and C++ are not the same with this. So first you'd have to decide which one you want.

Comment: i work at arduino so as they say it is a system with  c/c++ but ok lets say C is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `enum` looks something like:

```
enum /* ... */
{
  V1,
  V2,
  /* ... */ 
  VN
};
```

You can use the condition:

```
if (v < V1 || v > VN)
{
  /* invalid */
}
```

However, if you give specific values, you have to check against every value. Macros can help you a bit.

There is also an aspect on the standard on this point, which says that, in:

```
enum /* ... */
{
  V1 = 0,
  V2 = 2,
};
```

`1` is a valid value for an `enum /*...*/` type. Therefore you have to elaborate a bit more what "enumeration type check" means for you.

Comment: so this is like if i check the value to be between 0 and maxValueOfEnum since enum at c starts from 0 automatically,and there is no problem if the enum type does not "jump" any integer

Answer (score 0):

An enum in [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) is just an integer, so there is no way to check whether it belongs to a specific enum type.

Comment: yes but in this specific case enum is used to pass this integers, so i think that this works here.But if was not what should i do